# How to get last node of XML file in QT?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, parsing, qdomdocument

In my current project i am parsing the XML file using QDomDocument class. My XML file look like bellow:

```
<string>
<Data>
    <Details>
        <Content>
            <Name>James</Name>
            <DOB>30/09/1980</DOB>
            <MobileNo/>
            <Address>USA</Address>
        </Content>
        <Content>
            <Name>Ram</Name>
            <DOB>30/09/1995</DOB>
            <MobileNo>9876543210</MobileNo>
            <Address>India</Address>
        </Content>
        <Content>
            <Name>Jack</Name>
            <DOB/>
            <MobileNo>9876543210</MobileNo>
            <Address>UK</Address>
        </Content>
    </Details>
</Data>
```

In XML file number of `<Content>` tags. How I print last `<Content>` tag with its all data with respective tag name. My output will like:

```
<Content>
      <Name>Jack</Name>
      <DOB/>
      <MobileNo>9876543210</MobileNo>
      <Address>UK</Address>
</Content>
```

Can anyone give me some sample code for this that work me in QT(C++)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tested this so there might be some mistake in the code. However looking at the Qt documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomelement.html), I believe you should be able to achieve your goal by doing something like this:

```
QDomDocument doc = // ...
QDomElement root = doc.firstChildElement("string");
QDomElement elt = root.firstChildElement("Data")
        .firstChildElement("Details")
        .lastChildElement("Content");

QDomNamedNodeMap nma = elt.attributes();
int nmaLength = nma.length();
for (int i=0; i<nmaLength; ++i) {
    QDomAttr attr = nma.item(i).toAttr();
    qDebug() << attr.name().toLocal8Bit().constData() << ": " 
            << attr.value().toLocal8Bit().constData();
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your time and reply. For me your for loop is not working. it print blank output and output of nma.lenght() is zero. If i manually set nmaLenght=10, then in output it print 10 blank lines